# BitmapData lock and unlock not working on android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, image-processing, air, bitmapdata

The following code will erase a bitmap (brush akk droplet) from another bitmap (akka 

The code works great on PC and pretty ok performacewise.

When i test it on more android devices, it doesn't work. No matter if is a high end device or a slower one. I've made some tests and found out the problem is lock() and unlock() functions from BitmapData. It simply doesn't update the image on device, only once.

 I've tried to remove  them, but the then it lags alot. Also the performace drop is noticeable on PC too.
Does anyone know a solution, where am I doing wrong?

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var m:BitmapData = new water_pattern;
var b:BitmapData = new droplet;

var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(m);

var bla = new blabla();
addChild(bla);
bla.addChild(bm);

function p($x,$y){


var refPoint = new Point($x-b.width/2,$y-b.height/2);
for(var i=0;i<b.width;i++)
for(var j=0;j<b.height;j++)
{
    var a:uint = (b.getPixel32(i,j)>> 24) & 0xFF;
    a=0xFF-a;
    var tp:uint = m.getPixel32(refPoint.x+i,refPoint.y+j);
    var tp_trans:uint = (tp >> 24)&0xFF;
    if(tp_trans>a){

        tp=(tp&0x00FFFFFF)|(a<<24);
        m.setPixel32(refPoint.x+i,refPoint.y+j,tp);
    }
}

//for(var k=0;k<10000000;k++){};
}
var k=1;
var md = function(e)
{
    m.lock();
    p(bm.mouseX,bm.mouseY);
    m.unlock();
};

bla.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(e)
{
    bla.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME,md);
});
bla.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(e)
{
    bla.removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME,md);
});
```

---

I've reworked the code :

```
public function draw($x, $y)
        {

            var refPoint = new Point($x - brush.width / 2, $y - brush.height / 2);
            var r:Rectangle = new Rectangle(refPoint.x, refPoint.y, brush.width, brush.height);

             var pv:Vector.<uint> = pattern.getVector(r);
             var bv:Vector.<uint> = brush.getVector(brush.rect);


             for (var i = 0; i < bv.length; i++)
                {
                    var a:uint = (bv[i]>>24) &0xFF;
                    a = 0xFF - a;
                    var tp:uint = pv[i];
                    var tp_trans:uint = (tp >> 24) & 0xFF;

                //  trace(a.toString(16) + " vs " + tp_trans.toString(16));
                    if (tp_trans > a)
                    {

                        tp = (tp & 0x00FFFFFF) | (a << 24);
                        //      trace("??>" + tp);
                        pv[i] = tp;
                    }
                }

               pattern.setVector(r, pv);
        }
```

Now it works, but still it is pretty slow on device. That before i saw Jeff Ward's comment, so i changed it to render mode on CPU. It works fast. 
The big problem is in CPU mode the game is very slow compared to GPU. Yet this script is fast on CPU but unusable slow on GPU.

So I've tried again the first code and surprise. It works. Jeff Ward, thank you, you're a genius. 
Now the question remains is why? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Are you using GPU renderMode, or direct?

Comment: Have you tried direct?  I wonder if GPU render mode doesn't notice that kind of update to the underlying bitmapdata.  Try `bm.alpha = 0.98+0.02*Math.random();` after the `unlock()` statement, or perhaps re-assign the bitmapdata:  `bm.bitmapData = m;`

Comment: Yeah, it works in direct. Though while this works like a charm the rest of my game is laggy. I don't understand to be honest how something so simple gets laggy on GPU mode and doesn't work and how it does on direct, but other stuff that were working just fine are getting laggy

Comment: GPU and direct modes take entirely different approaches to GPU acceleration, so they'll be fast/slow in different situations.  Regardless, did those tricks make GPU mode work?  Or maybe `bm.filters = [];`  You need to get GPU mode to realize you've changed the BitmapData contents, and it needs to re-upload the texture (which itself could be a laggy operation, depending on the size of the bitmap).

Comment: Yes, they do work, they worked from the start, but the it is very laggy on GPU mode, while o CPU/direct, is very fast.

Comment: In GPU mode, changing any pixel in a Bitmap requires a re-upload of the full bitmap, so it's the size of Bitmap that's the limiting factor.  In direct mode, it blits only the portions of the screen that have been updated.  So I'd guess some parts of the game change a lot of the screen at once (slow in direct mode), and this effect changes a large bitmap, but only a little bit at a time (slow in GPU mode).

Comment: I see, and is there any way to stop flash fro reuploading the full bitmap, like working with a virtual bitmap or something?

Comment: If you know you're only going to modify a portion of the bitmap, split it into parts (multiple bitmaps) and only change some of them.

Comment: I thought so. Petty there is hybrid rendering mode. Add an answer to the question so i can mark it as answered.

Comment: Also maybe the answer would be more relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827049/gpu-vs-cpu-render-mode-adobe-air?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question, sometimes GPU mode doesn't pick up changes into the underlying bitmapdata.  Try *any one* of these operations after your `unlock()` to 'hint' that it should re-upload the bitmap data:

```
bm.filters = [];
bm.bitmapData = m;
bm.alpha = 0.98+Math.random()*0.02;
```

But as you found, uploading bitmapdata can be slow.  To clarify GPU/direct render modes:

In GPU mode, changing any pixel in a Bitmap requires a re-upload of the full bitmap, so it's the size of Bitmap that's the limiting factor. In direct mode, it blits only the portions of the screen that have been updated. So I'd guess some parts of the game change a lot of the screen at once (slow in direct mode), whereas this effect changes a large bitmap, but only a little bit at a time (slow in GPU mode).

You have to get creative to maximize your performance wrt GPUs:

1. In GPU mode, split the effect into many bitmaps, and only change as few as possible for any given frame. (medium effort)
2. Use [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) GPU-accelerated framework and Starling filters (GPU shaders) to achieve your effect (effort depends on how much you have invested in your game already), see [a couple](http://blog.onebyonedesign.com/actionscript/starling-filter-collection/) of [examples](http://thonbo.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/185/)