# GPU vs CPU render mode Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, gpu, cpu, render

I had the following question:
[BitmapData lock and unlock not working on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785797/bitmapdata-lock-and-unlock-not-working-on-android)

Now, encountering that issue, reading about render mode, I'm very confused how a script that simple fails in GPU mode,but is very fast on CPU mode.

**So the question is, how GPU mode works and how CPU mode works for adobe air? And why on GPU most of the stuff works better, but not that script**

Note: Base bitmap size should be bigger than 1400x1400

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations on `GPU` render mode.

Adobe recommends `direct` render mode. See following lines from Adobe help,

Note: In order to leverage GPU acceleration of Flash content with AIR for mobile platforms, Adobe recommends that you use renderMode="direct" (that is, Stage3D) rather than renderMode="gpu".

For more info see [Adobe GPU render mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html)

Comment: That is true, but i need the GPU render mode. I've read this and even more, still i've tried in many methods from copyPixels, to draw with blending mode. But all are laggy when dealing with invisible pixels. I was wondering if there is a workaround?